# How to click on specific element out of the webelements in selenium webdriver in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

If the date from the list of dates is matching with the given date which is string format then it should click on that element from that list of dates which when fetched is converted to string only.
I have list of dates like below when converted to string:

```
2017-10-13  
2017-09-29  
2017-09-22  
2017-09-15  
2017-09-08  
2017-09-01  
2017-08-25  
2017-08-18
```

So now if the input which is `"2017-Sep-29"` which when parsed to another format gives `2017-09-29` matches with the second date from the list then it should be clicked but it is throwing an error.

Below is my java code with comments :

```
WebDriver driver;
List<WebElement> stageListOfFilters;
String finalSnapshot = "", finalSnapshot1 = "";

@Test
public void getDateAndclick()
{
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    try {
        Date varDate = dateFormat.parse("18-Aug-2017");
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        finalSnapshot1 = dateFormat.format(varDate).toString();
        System.out.println("Date: " + finalSnapshot1); // Prints 2017-08-18
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(config.getsnapshotFilter())).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        finalSnap = finalSnapshot1.substring(5, 10);
        System.out.println("Date for final Comparison: " + finalSnap); // Prints 08-18 since i want to click on 18th august date
        stageListOfFilters = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='QvFrame DS']")); // This collects the list
                                                                                            // of dates which is
                                                                                            // fetched later on in
                                                                                            // for loop
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        for (int i = 0; i < stageListOfFilters.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(stageListOfFilters.get(i).getText());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            if (finalSnap.contains(stageListOfFilters.get(i).getText())) {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='QvFrame DS']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[" + i + "]")) 
                        .click();// If it matches at that index then it should click on element present at that index  
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So now it should click on the last element since date which is being passed is `18th August` but it still clicks on `2017-09-29`. I figured out that I am not getting value using `get(i).getText()` in `if loop` which is under `for loop`. Why is it so ?
Code for getAttribute("title") data :

```
stageListOfFilters = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DS']")); // This collects the list
                                                                                    // of dates which is
                                                                                    // fetched later on in
                                                                                    // for loop

            for (WebElement element : stageListOfFilters) {
                System.out.println("Dates are: " + element.getAttribute("title"));
            }
```

Comment: never use compound class names for locating webElements. Replace `@class='QvFrame DS'` in your xpath with a concrete attribute. Your logic seems fine. The problem is with the locator string. Fix it with a better tag position relative to date text.

Comment: Is this statement "stageListOfFilters = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='QvFrame DS']"));" giving you list of elements ? Please check.

Comment: @SandipanPramanik yes it gives the list of dates which i have already posted in above question

Comment: @Manmohan_singh can you elaborate with some code which would be easy to understand.

Comment: @siddhesh kalgaonkar, it is very difficult to find the reason of error without debugging. while you are opening the the list to get the date and closing it, DOM might have chaged. In that case you might get stale element exception. So put entire code in try catch block and implement webdriver wait, this will help you to debug.

Comment: okay I have implemented implicit wait . Let me put my code in try catch block and ll let u know

Comment: I tried but same error @SandipanPramanik

Comment: Aynone pls help

Comment: can you share the html code for the list of dates part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to select the proper xpath of the date list. I solved it now and below is my working code which fulfills my expectations. For css you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432949/loops-logic-not-working-as-expected-in-java-selenium) link:

```
try {
            Date varDate = dateFormat.parse("01-Sep-2017");
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // 2017-08-18
            finalSnapshot1 = dateFormat.format(varDate).toString();
            System.out.println("Date: " + finalSnapshot1); // Prints 2017-08-18
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(config.getsnapshotFilter())).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            stageListOfFilters = driver
                    .findElements(By.xpath("(//*[@class='QvFrame DS'])[1]/div/div/div[1]/child::div")); // This collects
                                                                                                        // the list
            // of dates which is
            // fetched later on in
            // for loop
            System.out.println("Size" + stageListOfFilters.size());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            for (int i = 1; i < stageListOfFilters.size(); i++) {

                if (finalSnapshot1.equals(stageListOfFilters.get(i).getText())) {
                    System.out.println("Filters list value: " + stageListOfFilters.get(i).getText());
                    System.out.println("Value to be compared: " + finalSnapshot1);
                    i = i + 1;
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='QvFrame DS']/div/div/div[1]/div[" + i + "]/div[1]"))
                            .click();
                    System.out.println("Value of i: " + i +" and Date is: "+ finalSnapshot1.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I solved it finally after 21 days. LOL

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the web elements in loop like show below:

```
stageListOfFilters = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='QvFrame DS']")); 
Thread.sleep(2000);
for ( WebElement we: stageListOfFilters ) { 
    System.out.println(stageListOfFilters.getText());
    if (finalSnapshot1.contains(we.getText())) {
        we.click(); 
        System.out.println("Data" + we.getText());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is giving the same error

Comment: Any other suggestions ?

Comment: `System.out.println("Data" + we.getText());` can you remove this and try?If the DOM will update once you select the data,then it might cause the problem.Or put this link before click.

Comment: Yes i commented that part and tried but still the same issue

Comment: Can you check, if that element comes under any iframe?

Comment: there is no iframe from ui code level perspective. If you want i can paste that part of code as well

Comment: Can you tell me some site where i can reproduce this kind of case?So that i can try it locally.That might help you i think.

Comment: No Sudha  I cant disclose this link. Can you suggest me some other solution. I tried my best searching for some relevant solution but in vain

Comment: I tried and now I am able to click on the date from the list but even if i pass some other date it still clicks on first element only. I have updated my code. can you check and tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: The logic looks fine to me.Can you check the xpath.Can try with the string(date) instead of the index?

Comment: Can you go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432949/loops-logic-not-working-as-expected-in-java-selenium i have explained my problem for xpath

Comment: Can you please try this xpath `.//*[@class='QvFrame DS']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[contains(@title,finalSnap)]`.

Comment: Okay i ll try and ll let u know in short period

Comment: I have modified my code for getting values from title attribute but i am getting empty values . Please tell me where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching the date value correctly using the elements then I believe the problem could be in your `"if"` condition. I believe the `finalSnap` value is `"08-18"` and whereas `"stageListOfFilters.get(i).getText()"` is fetching the date as `"2017-08-18"`. The below "If" condition inside the for loop will be always false since you are checking if `"08-18"` contains `"2017-08-18"` or not.

```
if (finalSnap.contains(stageListOfFilters.get(i).getText())) { //this condition check is false

     //ur code
}
```

You should be comparing `"2017-08-18"` with `"08-18"` and not the reverse way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i solved my problem :)

Comment: i was not able to get proper xpath for those elements.