# Loops logic not working as expected in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I want to check whether value which is passed is matching the value in `if loop` and if its matching then it should execute the code which is in `if loop`. What happens is everytime I run it selects only first value and doesn't check for the other values. I am unable to figure out whats wrong with my logic. Below is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < stageListOfFilters.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(stageListOfFilters.get(i).getText());

                if (finalSnapshot1.toString().equals(stageListOfFilters.get(i).getText())) {

                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DS']/div/div/div[1]/div[" + i + "]/div[1]")).click();

                    System.out.println("Value of i: " + i);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
            }
```

Do let me know if any additional information is required. For more details please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300257/how-to-click-on-specific-element-out-of-the-webelements-in-selenium-webdriver-in)  link.

[image]

Below you can see the list of snapshot date filter and the css corresponding to it. Now i want to click on the matching title. How can i do it ?
I tried below code for getting data from title attribute but gives null values:

```
stageListOfFilters = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DS']")); // This collects the list
                                                                                    // of dates which is
                                                                                    // fetched later on in
                                                                                    // for loop

            for (WebElement element : stageListOfFilters) {
                System.out.println("Dates are: " + element.getAttribute("title"));
            }
```

Comment: My problem is not resolved since one week that's why I am forced to post this as a question again.

Comment: can you share the html code for the stageListOfFilters?

Comment: May be you are retrieving wrong xpath or xpath index behaves differently in different browser. Can you send me the html code in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: You should be able to identify the issue by running the code step by step and by checking that the composed XPath returns the expected element in the browser's console. That said, an index in an XPath starts at `1` but your loop starts at `0`.

Comment: @siddheshkalgaonkar, share your HTML for stageListOfFilters elements.

Comment: Yes you were right there is some problem with my xpath. I am not able to get the correct xpath. I am attaching image of list and css. I hope it would be easier for you guys to help me now. I have modified my question

Comment: anybody help please

Comment: I updated my code for getting data from title attribute but getting null data. Can anyone help me with these ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be simple issue like spaces around the string edges. Better to remove spaces around the edge of string, then compare it. like,

```
if (finalSnapshot1.toString().trim().equals(stageListOfFilters.get(i).getText().trim())) {
```

In code,

```
for (int i = 0; i < stageListOfFilters.size(); i++) {
   System.out.println(stageListOfFilters.get(i).getText());

   if (finalSnapshot1.toString().trim().equals(stageListOfFilters.get(i).getText().trim())) {

     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DS']/div/div/div[1]/div[" + i + "]/div[1]")).click();
     System.out.println("Value of i: " + i);
     Thread.sleep(2000);
   }
 }
```

Comment: I have modified my question @Murthi. I hope so it would be easier to help me now

Comment: Instead of get text method, you can use getAttribute("title") in the if condition

Comment: Okay then do i need to convert it to string ? like getAttribute().toString()?

Comment: driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DS']")) i am not able to use getAtrribute method for this xpath. What should i do ?

Comment: can you suggest something

Comment: i have modified my xpath and tried getting values from title attribute but getting null values. I have update my code.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to select the proper xpath of the date list. I solved it now and below is my working code which fulfills my expectations.

```
try {
            Date varDate = dateFormat.parse("01-Sep-2017");
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // 2017-08-18
            finalSnapshot1 = dateFormat.format(varDate).toString();
            System.out.println("Date: " + finalSnapshot1); // Prints 2017-08-18
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(config.getsnapshotFilter())).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            stageListOfFilters = driver
                    .findElements(By.xpath("(//*[@class='QvFrame DS'])[1]/div/div/div[1]/child::div")); // This collects
                                                                                                        // the list
            // of dates which is
            // fetched later on in
            // for loop
            System.out.println("Size" + stageListOfFilters.size());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            for (int i = 1; i < stageListOfFilters.size(); i++) {

                if (finalSnapshot1.equals(stageListOfFilters.get(i).getText())) {
                    System.out.println("Filters list value: " + stageListOfFilters.get(i).getText());
                    System.out.println("Value to be compared: " + finalSnapshot1);
                    i = i + 1;
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='QvFrame DS']/div/div/div[1]/div[" + i + "]/div[1]"))
                            .click();
                    System.out.println("Value of i: " + i +" and Date is: "+ finalSnapshot1.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks everyone for your help. I solved it finally after 21 days. LOL !